# How many class for classification model?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I'm working on a Machine Learning classification problem. Where I need to classify input data into 8 classes + none of the classes. Should I be considering it as a classification of 9 classes ?

Comment: Yes. That is what you will need to do. Just treat none as another class.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do with this data.

If you are interested in the 'none' class as interesting outliers, or they are mainly noise, you can try run binary classification with other 8 classes vs the 'none' class, or some outlier detection algorithm.

On the other hand, if the 'none' class is not different from the other ones, then I don't see the point of treating it differently.